# Que significa esta porcion de codigo en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Observe esta linea de codigo de laravel en internet, sin embargo no se de que forma se interpreta. 
La linea es la siguiente:

```
$oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
```

Agradecería su explicación.

Comment: tu pregunta es que hace ese codigo; o que significa el `?` y el `:`

Comment: Si que hace y que significa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primera pergunta** : que hace este codigo

```
$oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
```

el  `Session::has('cart')` Determinar si existe un elemento en la sesión en este caso **`cart`**

`Session::get('cart')` obtiene el valor de la sesion

**Segunda Pregunta** : que significa el `?` y el `:` no es mas que un if corto para asignar por lo general se hace de esta forma:

```
if (Session::has('cart')){
   $oldCart =  Session::get('cart') 
}else{
   $oldCart =  null;
}
```

se lee asi : `?` entonces y el `:` de lo contrario

> Es obligado mantener este orden , es decir, primero va el `?` y luego
>   el  `:`
>
> Es muy comun verlos en otro lenguajes de programación

Comment: Gracias no sabia como se interpretaba pero ahora si, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Usa **if en linea** u **operador ternario** para asignar el valor de la variable *oldCart*. Si se cumple la expresión (condición) antes de "?" regresa el valor entre "?" y ":" de lo contrario, regresa el valor después de ":".

- Si la sesión tiene definida *cart*, dicho valor se asigna a *oldCart*.
- Si la sesión **NO** tiene definida *cart* el valor de *oldCart* será nulo.